# Iterating over sets of sets

Tags: java, iterator, set

I am attempting to write a program that iterates over a set of sets.  In the example code below, I am getting an error that stating that iter.next() is of type object rather than a set of strings.  I am having some other more mysterious issues with iterating over sets of sets as well.  Any suggestions?

```
            Set<String> dogs= new HashSet<String>();
            dogs.add("Irish Setter");
            dogs.add("Poodle");
            dogs.add("Pug");
            dogs.add("Beagle");

            Set<String> cats = new HashSet<String>();
            cats.add("Himalayan");
            cats.add("Persian");

            Set<Set<String>> allAnimals = new HashSet<Set<String>>();                   
            allAnimals.add(cats);
            allAnimals.add(dogs);

            Iterator iter = allAnimals.iterator();            
            System.out.println(allAnimals.size());

            while (iter.hasNext()) 
            {
                System.out.println(iter.next().size());
            }
```

---

A related question with the same setup (minus the loop).
The code fragment below results in a final output that includes tildes.  But I don't want to change allAnimals as I go!  How can I edit extension without affecting the larger set (allAnimals).

```
 for (Set<String> extension : allAnimals) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Set size: " + extension.size());
                    extension.add("~");     
                    System.out.println(extension);
                }   

                System.out.println(allAnimals);
```

Comment: You don't need to call `someSet.clear();` right after creating a set.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm nervous about not initiating variables so I go overboard sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `allAnimals` variable is of type `Set<Set<String>>`, however, when you ask its `Iterator` you "forget" the type information. According to the compiler, your iterator just contains `Object`s. Change the line where you get the `Iterator` to this

```
Iterator<Set<String>> iter = allAnimals.iterator();
```

and all should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Use an enhanced for loop for traversing the sets, is easier than using an iterator:

```
for (Set<String> names : allAnimals) {
    System.out.println(names.size());
}
```

For example, to traverse all the animal's names:

```
for (Set<String> names : allAnimals) {
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2623054 This is good advice, I recommend following it.  However, I would also recommend marking mthmulders answer as the accepted one, as it precisely identifies the problem.

Comment: This method seems to result in a new error: "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Comment: `Set` is an instance of `Iterable`. You must be doing something wrong, because the above works, and it's the recommended way to iterate nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention the `type` on which your iterator is defined. So as far as it is concerned it expects an object as next.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a (nested) foreach loop:

```
for(Set<String> animals : allAnimals) {
    int size = animals.size(); // if you want it
    for (String animal : animals) {
        // do something with the name
    }
}
```